# How dynamic connectivity and union-find related?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, union-find

According to Wikipedia:

> A [dynamic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity) structure is a data structure that dynamically maintains information about the connected components of a graph.

And:

> A [union–find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure is a data structure that tracks a set of elements partitioned into a number of disjoint (non-overlapping) subsets.

At first glance, there is little relationship between these data structures. But almost every article, that mentions dynamic connectivity, glimpses at union-find too. So, I wonder how are these two related?

Comment: I feel it's more like that these two data structures can be used to find connectivity related information about the graphs. I doubt there is any direct correlation between these two structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article about [dynamic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity):

> The set V of vertices of the graph is fixed, but the set E of edges can change. The three cases, in order of difficulty, are:
>
> - Edges are only added to the graph (this can be called incremental connectivity);
> - Edges are only deleted from the graph (this can be called decremental connectivity);
> - Edges can be either added or deleted (this can be called fully dynamic connectivity).

A union-find data structure (also known as a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)) can be used in the first case. You can use the **union** operation to join two components when adding an edge, and the **find** operation to test whether two vertices are in the same component. However, a union-find data structure has no operation to support deleting an edge, splitting a component into two newly-disconnected components; so it cannot be used to solve the other two cases of the dynamic connectivity problem.

Comment: Does that mean union-find problem is a special case of dynamic connectivity problem? Or union-find is a way of solving dynamic connectivity problem?

Comment: Union-find is a way of solving the first kind of dynamic connectivity problem.